# Qt 6.3.0 - Is the QtWebEngine object able to manage the display in offline mode?

Tags: qt, offline-caching, qtwebengine

I am developing a Qt application displaying a `WebEngineView`.

The cache is working properly.

I would like to go further by integrating an offline mode:
without a network, the application must display the web page based on its cache (like the standard process of a browser like Chrome).
For now, despite setting the `QWebEngineProfile`, `QQuickWebEngineProfile` and `QWebEngineSettings` objects, the page displays: ["No internet ... ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQlTd.png)

Does anyone know or have implemented this feature before?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Qt version: `6.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that without setting up a proxy or overriding HTTP/HTTPS